# OpenGL. приближение сцены для соответствия размеру приложения

Tags: opengles

Я использую перспективную матрицу проекции и gluLookAt в качестве матрицы просмотра. Я пытаюсь реализовать функцию зума(приближения) камеры к сцене/Соответственно, как я подумал, чтобы сцена влезла в экран полностью, вне зависимости от расстановки камеры, нужно умножать вершины не только на матрицу мира, но и на матрицу вида, но я сразу заметил баг, цель теперь почти всегда находится за пределами реальной сцены (BoundBox'а), а не по середине, и всегда в разных местах. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, в чем проблема или где я делаю ошибку?

Comment: *"реализовать функцию зума (приближения) камеры к сцене, чтобы она соответствовала размеру окна приложения"* - переформулируйте пожалуйста и приведите пример. *"сцена не увеличивается до полноэкранного размера при взгляде (положении камеры) сбоку"* - Камере и Миру должно быть все равно на свое взаимное расположение. Вероятно вы по какой-то из осей в Мире это делаете, а не по их проекциям из Камеры.

Comment: Сцена может находится далеко от камеры, при нажатии кнопки отвечающей за эту функцию, происходит зум,т.е. мы приближаем камеру так, что бы верхние и нижние грани сцены вписались ровно в окно просмотра, либо левая и правая грань, если сцена в ширину больше, чем в высоту. В случае если соотношение сторон БаундБокса и окна приложения одинаковые, вписало полностью, т.е. увеличилась ровно на весь экран.

Comment: *"Я вычисляю минимальные-максимальные координаты граничащого прямоугольника"* - вот тут наверное вам стоит перейти на ограничивающий куб сцены.